# what is cause of error [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 1260 exit signal Segmentation fault (11) CENTOS 7.9

Tags: linux, nginx

I am using apache2 server with php and Engintron Nginx

CENTOS 7.9

> [Sat Oct 02 16:54:14.334779 2021] [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052:
> child pid 3314 exit signal Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02
> 16:54:14.334820 2021] [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3315
> exit signal Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:14.334828 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3316 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:14.334835 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3317 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:14.334843 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3318 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:14.334849 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3319 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:14.334856 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3320 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:14.335007 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3321 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:15.336067 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3330 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:15.336102 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3331 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:15.336112 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3332 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:15.336118 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3333 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:15.336124 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3334 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:15.336129 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3335 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:15.336134 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3336 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:15.336141 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3337 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:15.336314 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3340 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:16.337893 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3339 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:16.337940 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3341 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:16.337946 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3342 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:17.340298 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3343 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:17.340343 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3344 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:17.340353 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3345 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:17.340362 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3346 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:18.347122 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3362 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:18.347227 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3367 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:18.347252 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3368 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:19.352435 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3371 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:19.352485 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3372 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:19.352494 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3373 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:19.352502 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3374 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:20.360845 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3379 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:20.360877 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3380 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:20.360883 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3381 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:20.360890 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3382 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:20.360896 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3383 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sat Oct 02 16:54:20.360901 2021]
> [core:notice] [pid 797] AH00052: child pid 3384 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11)

And it causes the site to slow down and stop constantly

Answer (score 1):

The `Segmentation fault` basically means that a PHP process has attempted to access a restricted area of memory (a memory access violation).

This is not easy to track or solve as it involve debugging your software but please check this out to get a better idea.

[Fixing Apache Segmentation Faults Caused by PHP](https://www.omh.cc/blog/2008/mar/6/fixing-apache-segmentation-faults-caused-php/)